# jQuery: any opacity value other than 1 behaves like 0

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is a weird one for me, as all of the elements this code applies to work just fine, except for one. Rather frustrating. I've tested this on chrome, firefox, and iOS safari.

If it would help, this is a craftcms project, but I don't think it's relevant.

I'm fading elements in / out based on the scrollTop() position of the page. I can see the opacity is being set in chrome's developer tools properly on all elements and that there's no other opacity overriding it.

**The issue is that the text inside the blue element you see below is invisible even though its opacity has been set to 0.81 with jquery**

The image below is of the element for which things aren't working.

[image: I'm at a loss.]

Here is the relevant section of my twig template:

```
<section id="home-about" class="home-section bghidden">
    <div class="inner scrollHide">
        {{entry.aboutPreview}}
        <a href="/about" class="button-green">
            <span>learn more</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <img id="collage" class="scrollHide" srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedPNG) }}"
        sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 40vw, 100vw" src="{{collage.url}}" />
</section>
<section id="home-videos" class="home-section">
    <div id="home-interviews" data-scroll-speed="3">
        <div class="inner scrollHide">
            {{entry.interviewsPreview}}
            <a href="/design" class="button-blue">
                <span>see interviews</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This function calculates the opacity values:

```
function showOnScroll() {
    var page = $("body").attr('class').split(" ")[0],
        offsets = {
            home: [0.5, 0.75],
            italiaIndex: [0, 0.5],
            team: [0, 0.5],
            v: [0.5, 0.75]
        };

    if (offsets[page]) {
        $entries.each(function(ind, el) {
            var $entry = ind !== 0 ? $entries.eq(ind - 1) : $entries.eq(0),
                $scrollStart = ind !== 0 ? parseFloat($entry.attr('data-offset')) + (parseFloat($entry.attr('data-height')) * offsets[page][0]) : 0,
                $scrollEnd = ind !== 0 ? parseFloat($entry.attr('data-offset')) + (parseFloat($entry.attr('data-height')) * offsets[page][1]) : 0,
                $opacity;
            if (scrollPos > $scrollStart && scrollPos < $scrollEnd) {
                $opacity = ((scrollPos - $scrollStart) / ($scrollEnd - $scrollStart)).toFixed(2);
            } else if (scrollPos <= $scrollStart) {
                $opacity = 0;
            } else if (scrollPos >= $scrollEnd) {
                $opacity = 1;
            }
            $entries.eq(ind).find(".scrollHide").css('opacity', $opacity);
        });
    }
}
```

And this listener calls the above function:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    this.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
        /*
          Irrelevant code removed
        */
        parallax();
        showOnScroll();
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean that the problem is that the blue box doesn't overlap the green one in the second screenshot?

Comment: Could you share a simple HTML/CSS snippet which reproduces that problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please clarify.

Comment: @Christoph The issue is that in the bottom screenshot the text isn't visible at all.

Comment: Opacity can change z-index. That's what I'd look into https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @spencerlarry I've clarified in the post, but the issue is that elements of opacity 0.81 (or anything besides 1) are not visible.

Comment: As @Gothdo said, please create a [mcve] so that we can have a look at it live.

Comment: Can't really explain it, but simplifying my code solved it. Thanks for the good read though @AR7, that's a new level of understanding for me.

Comment: @Tortilaman Please answer your own question if you have solved it yourself (this certainly is permitted, though there may be a delay).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't post the CSS in my question, but after simplifying the HTML I think that the issue had something to do with using `mix-blend-mode: multiply` on a `div::after` element. This might've had an effect on the stacking order, but I can't really say for sure.